# Bava Metzia 34a

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, bava-metzia

Can you please help me on the first few lines of Bava Metzia 34a. Thank You. 
What is the exact translation:

מי יימר דמגנבא ואם תימצי לומר דמגנבא מי יימר דמשתכח גנב ואי משתכח גנב מי יימר דמשלם דלמא מודי ומפטר

Thanks again.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want. If you can translate other gemoros what do you find so difficult here.

Comment: http://halakhah.com/babamezia/babamezia_34.html

Answer (score 5):

Well to quote Artscroll Hakadosh:

> "מי יימר דמגנבא-**who is to say that [the deposit] will be stolen**"
>
> "ואם תימצי לומר דמגנבא-**and even if you can say who is to say** with certainty **that it will be stolen**"
>
> "מי יימר דמשתכח גנב -**who is to say that the thief will be apprehended?**"
>
> "ואי משתכח גנב-**and even if the thief is apprehended,**"
>
> "מי יימר דמשלם-**who is to say that [the thief] will pay?**"
>
> "דלמא מודי ומפטר-**Perhaps he will confess** his crime **and avoid** imposition of penalty payment
> .Thus since penalty payments are not likely to be forthcoming how can they be conveyed in advance?"

I hope I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

The following translation comes from Jacob Neusner (2011):

> b. ***Bava Metzia*** 34A
>   “. . . who can say for certain that the bailment is going to be stolen?
>   And if you choose to say that it is sure to be stolen, then who can say for sure that the thief is going to be found?
>   And if the thief is found,   who can say for certain that he will pay the restitution at all?
>   Perhaps he will confess his guilt and be exempt from having to pay double [but merely makes restitution of the beast]!”

**Source:**
Neusner, Jacob (2011). *[The Babylonian Talmud: A Translation and Commentary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1598565273)* (Vol. 14). Peabody: Hendrickson Publishers, 162.